# Complexity analysis of a recursion

Tags: time-complexity

A recursive algorithm has the following computation tree. The label on the node indicates the number of outgoing edges. This algorithm takes an input of length $n$ and at each processing, it results in $n - 1$ recursive calls. For each these calls/nodes, the size of the input decreases by $1$ from left to right. This pattern repeats.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to come up with a complexity analysis for this. It feels like there's some mathematical pattern/sequence here but I'm not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Vertices in your tree correspond to decreasing sequences starting at $n$. We can identify each such subsequence with a subset of $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, and consequently, your tree contains $2^n$ vertices. Consequently, assuming the processing per node is $O(1)$, your algorithm runs in time $\Theta(2^n)$.

The same method also allows us to count directly the number of vertices labelled $m$: there are $2^{n-m-1}$ of these for $m \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, and one labelled $n$ (the root).

---

Here is another way to solve this, using a recurrence. Let $T(n)$ be the size of the tree when the root is labelled $n$. Then $T(0) = 1$ and
$$
T(n + 1) = 1 + \sum_{m=0}^n T(m).
$$
This formula actually works also for $n = -1$. In order to solve this recurrence, observe that
$$
T(n+1) = 1 + \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} T(m) + T(n) = 2T(n),
$$
and so $T(n) = 2^n T(0) = 2^n$.